# SVN: Dealing with svn object of the same name is already scheduled for addition

Tags: svn

Everytime I svn update I get the following error

```
Failed to add file path/to/file: object of the same name is already scheduled for addition
```

I tried to rename the file, delete it...but the error is still there.

I've read this article and say something about reverting...but I still can't understand how to do it...
http://thrustlabs.com/blog/2007/04/04/dealing-with-svn-object-of-the-same-name-is-already-scheduled-for-addition-errors-on-windows/

Thanks.

Comment: Mine is `svn: Failed to add file 'path/to/some.file': object of the same name already exists` but otherwise the same problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What client are you using? For the "plain" svn client, see if any of these solve your problems:

```
cd /path/to/directory/with/suspected/duplicate
svn revert .
svn cleanup
svn update
```

If you use TortoiseSVN, rightclick on the folder with issues, then: TortoiseSVN->Revert, 
TortoiseSVN->Clean up and SVN Update.

Comment: I connect via ssh using Putty. This will only affect my instance right and not others? Sorry...I'm quite a beginner at this.

Comment: For others... I tried svn cleanup, it didn't work. svn revert path/to/file is what works^^ Thanks Martin!

Comment: Sadly, this did not work for me. `svn: Failed to add file 'path/to/some.file': object of the same name already exists` still occurs. :(  Status says nothing is pending, nothing special about that file.  Contents as expected.  If I delete the file, an update will put it back and then fuss that it can't add it. I up-voted anyway, as this is best answer I've seen.

Comment: @JesseChisholm you could try a `svn delete` on the file and see if you can add it normally after that.

Comment: @MartinSchapendonk Yes, what finally worked is `svn rm some.file; svn ci; svn up .;` which reported the delete, then reported the add as successful.  Apparently the file was originally added from two different sandboxes before either were committed.  The first one to commit wins.

Answer (score 1):

Revert is easy: it undoes all changes in your working copy. So, revert the directory and that will un-do the add operation you applied to the file. That should sort your problems out.

After reverting, update the directory.

Comment: Sadly, it does not undo the `pending` add. that is tied to the specific workspace, and must be removed before the revert to the master will work.